# An input-output explanation of a quantum photonic setting

Tags: photons, quantum-information, epr-experiment

I am a computer scientist specialising in quantum information processing.

I am currently struggling to understand the photonic setting in the figure below (coming from [this paper](https://opg.optica.org/optica/fulltext.cfm?uri=optica-9-2-152&id=469063)).

[image]

I wonder how a standard generic input $\alpha|\texttt{0}\rangle + \beta|\texttt{1}\rangle$ -- figure (a) -- maps to what it looks to me as a fixed input of two EPR pairs $|\Phi^{\texttt{+}}\rangle \otimes |\Phi^{\texttt{+}}\rangle$ -- figure (b) --.

I am not really used to read photonic settings. E.g. I don't know what is meant for *trigger*, nor for $e_i, o_i$.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Perhaps this question would have better luck in the [Quantum computing site](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed related to a question I posted there. But I think that this particular one finds a better audience here, where I assume there are some more experts on photonic settings.

Comment: related by OP: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/26885/55

Comment: I'm not flagging this as outright cross-posting because you at least did make a few changes between the posts. Still, in such cases linking together the posts is appreciated. And as I said in the other post, I think you're better off asking more specific questions about aspects of this. If you lack the necessary background of how these circuits work, you might also have a hard time understanding the answers. For example, I'd focus on the equivalence in Fig. (c) here. Or on how a PBS works, if you don't know that, etc.